# How to create readable stream that allows writing to it?

Tags: node.js

One of libraries I am using expects readable stream, for example:

```
library(fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file'))
```

But I would like to pass a file from memory (`Buffer`) instead from a file. How I can do that? Using node `0.10.x`.

```
var inMemoryFile = new Buffer('content', 'utf8');
library(/* readable stream of inMemoryFile? */)
```

---

solved:

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable
var stream = new Readable()
stream.push(new Buffer('content', 'utf8'))
stream.push(null) // finish
library(stream)
```

Comment: [Start with this article](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook), if you haven't already?  [The official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) are also helpful.

Comment: Thanks, it helped :)

Comment: Please post your solutions as an answer and accept it. This way it might be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is (Thanks @Matthew Bakaitis):

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable
var stream = new Readable()
stream.push(new Buffer('content', 'utf8'))
stream.push(null) // finish
library(stream)
```